# Is there a generic way to add items to any iterable in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to add items into any iterable in a type-agnostic way, but not all python iterables seem to have a standard interface/method for doing so.
lists use append(), sets use add(), etc.

Basically, something like this -

```
def add(anylist, item):
   # adds 'item' into 'anylist'
   # possibly return 'newlist' if 'anylist' is immutable (such as tuple, str)
   return newlist

x = add([1,2,3], 4) # x is now [1,2,3,4]
y = add('abcd', 'e') # y is now "abcde"
z = add((1,2,3), 4) # z is now (1,2,3,4)
```

Currently, I am making do by handling individual types on a case-by-case basis like so-

```
>>> def add(anylist, item):
...   if isinstance(anylist, list):
...      anylist.append(item)
...   elif isinstance(anylist, set):
...      anylist.add(item)
...   elif isinstance(anylist, str):
...      anylist += item
...   elif isinstance(anylist, tuple):
...      anylist += (item,)
...   return anylist
... 
>>> print add([1,2,3], 4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print add((1,2,3), 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> print add("123", '4')
1234
>>> print add({1,2,3}, 4)
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This is obviously sub-optimal because it doesn't work with *every* iterable.
Am I missing something?
I tried to make use of python's concatenate(+) operator to achieve this, but that didn't help either.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x += [4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = "123"
>>> y += "4"
>>> y
'1234'
```

as there's no easy way to convert 'item' to an iterable type either.

For eg, the following -

```
item = '4'
x = '123'
x += str(item) # x = '1234'
```

works, but lists do not behave the same way -

```
>>> item = 4
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x += list(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: @pistol2myhead, Yes, this works for a list, but how do I convert any item to the respective iterable type without checking for its type?
How would this work for a tuple, for instance?

Comment: You mean something like `type(x)(itertools.chain(x, [y]))`. That works for `isinstance(x, (set, list, tuple))` but not `str`.

Comment: What do you mean by "add any iterable"? It is not obvious how addition should work in every case. What about `dict` objects? Or user-defined containers/iterables? How about iterators? Can you constrain?

Comment: @DanD. nor dict, but sort-of the natural way one would want it to work with, say, a generator

Comment: @DanD.
Thanks for this.
This worked for list, tuple and set but not for str - as mentioned in your comment.
Guess I can handle str separately for now.

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic way to take one sequence an automatically create another sequence of the same type with one extra item. That's because not all sequences allow arbitrary values. For instance, a Python 3 `range` object (or an `xrange` in Python 2) computes its values on the fly, so there's no way to add a new value of your choice.

However, if you're only going to *iterate* over your sequence after adding the value to the end, you may be able to get what you want using `itertools.chain`, which returns an iterator.

```
import itertools

def add(iterable, value):
    return itertools.chain(iterable, [value])
```

You won't be able to pass the iterator directly to a `print` statement, but you can perhaps use some other kind of container, like a list to hold the values so you can print them.

```
print list(add((1,2,3), 4)) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4], doesn't try to produce a tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overloading operators in iterable classes, but the effort probably outweighs the benefit.

In any case, if you want to use + as a way of extending the list, you can create your own container class inheriting from list, and overload the .`__add__` method:

```
class my_list(list):
    def __add__(self, o):
        self.__getitem__(self).extend(o)

a = my_list()
a += [1] #a=[1]
a += [2] #a=[1,2]
```

Similarly, you extend all iterables.
Your proposed method of if-else is probably easier to maintain with language updates, so worth keeping this in mind if you decide to start extending the inbuilt classes.